# Is this vulnerable to SQL injection

Tags: php, sql, code-injection

I realize there are a lot of questions already about this. But my method isn't the same as theirs, so I wanted to know. I think I understand SQL, but I don't want to risk making a mistake in the future, so thanks for any help. (This is just a project I'm doing, not homework or anything important).

```
function checkLogin($username, $password) {
    $username = strtolower($username);
    connectToDatabase();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'");
    $dbpassword = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $rowuser = $row['username'];
  if($username != $row['username']) continue;
  $dbpassword = $row['password'];
  }
    if($dbpassword == "") {
        return false;
    }
    $genpass = generatePassword($password);
   return $genpass == $dbpassword;
}
```

So hit me with your best shot :)
And I don't think my method is as efficient as it could be. I don't understand php enough to understand what `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` is doing unfortunately.

Comment: SQL injection comes when strange values are supplied for $username or $password to your function.   If those values come from an externally supplied source, you're in trouble.

Comment: @Ira Baxter, It's coming from a POST, so I'm guessing that means I'm in trouble?

Comment: Consider that somebody might type in, for username, the text "' OR 'A=A".  Then your loop would try the password for all users, I think.  That would make it easier to guess a password.  If your SQL allows multiple statements in a query call, the username text might be "'; DELETE * FROM 'users' which would wipe out your user table, or an UPDATE statement that set the password of some user to a particular password, making it trivial to login with that password.  What you need to check is to check that the username string doesn't contain quote marks.

Comment: I +1ed every answer here. Anyone who lands on this page: there is **NO DOWNSIDE** to using a prepared statement. And you can sleep easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are taking an arbitrary string and placing it directly into an SQL statement, you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

( **EDITED** based on a comment below. )

The classic example of SQL injection is making a username such as the following:

```
Robert'); DROP TABLE users;--
```

[Obligatory XKCD link](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Explanation:

Given the "username" above, interpolation into your string results in:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='Robert'); DROP TABLE users;--'
```

The comment symbol `--` at the end is required to "get rid" of *your* closing quote, because I just substituted one of mine to end your select statement so that I could inject a DROP TABLE statement.

As @sarnold pointed out, PHP's `mysql_query` only executes a the first query in the string, so the above example (known as **[query stacking](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/guide-to-php-security-ch3.pdf)**) does not apply.  The function is explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php.

A better example can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/SQL_Injection). Here they use a username of

```
' OR 1 OR username = '
```

which interpolated becomes

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='' OR 1 OR username = ''
```

and which would cause your application to retrieve all users.

Comment: I just tried this, and it didn't drop my tables, why would that be?

Comment: That string is not a good example; by default, `mysql_query` [only executes the first query in the string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#91669). Leave it to PHP to try to solve a security using a hacky mechanism. *cough* magic quotes *cough*

Comment: Thanks to sarnold for that.  I didn't know that! +1

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes.

A perhaps more helpful answer is that you should never trust user input; prepared statements are the easiest way to protect against this, if you have PDO available. See [PDO Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username=?");
if ($stmt->execute($username)) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are an excellent description of your problem, however, I think they both overlook the best solution: use PHP's [PDO Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for your queries.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where username = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($username))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
```

This is a small, simple example. There are more sophisticated ways of using PDO that might fit your application better.

When you use PDO prepared statements you never need to manually escape anything and so long as you use this slightly different style, you will never write an SQL injection vulnerability *and* you don't have to maintain two variables per underlying "data" -- one sanitized, one as the user supplied it -- because only one is ever required.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes it is open to SQL injection.

This is because you are taking user input in the form of $username and putting it into your SQL statement without making sure it is clean.

This is a function that I like to use in my applications for the purpose of cleaning strings:

```
function escape($data) {
    $magicQuotes = get_magic_quotes_gpc();

    if(function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string')) {
        if($magicQuotes) {
            $data = stripslashes($data);
        }

        $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    }
    else {
        if(!$magicQuotes) {
            $data = addslashes($data);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$username = escape(strtolower($username));
connectToDatabase();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'");
```